# Django, html, css - Footer style applies to all the body

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a webpage structured as follows and I want to have a `background-color: #aa2222` property to apply only to the footer.

```
<body>
      {% block sidebar %}<!-- insert default navigation text for every page -->{% endblock %}
      {% block content %}<!-- default content text (typically empty) -->
      <!-- Navigation Bar -->
      <section class="navbarSection">
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
          ...
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- End of Navigation Bar -->
      <!-- Articles -->
      <section class="articleSection">
        <div class="articles" id="myArticles">
          {% for article in articles %}
          ...
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Footer -->
      <footer id="site-footer">
        <div id="footer1">
          <p> footer text </p>
        </div>
      </footer>
      <!-- End of Footer -->
</body>
```

The footer is styled as follows:

```
#footer1 {
background-color: #aa2222;
}
```

At the moment the page is displayed with all the body with `background-color:#aa2222` instead of only the footer.
It seems to be related to Django because using the code in a web editor it applies the background color properly only to the footer.
Could you please help?

**EDIT1**: as suggested, I tried to add a footer.html file in the templates folder as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="site-footer">
    <div id="footer1">
      <p> footer text </p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- End of Footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

Then I have added the tag `{% include "templates/footer.html" %}` in the `index.html` but I receive the error `TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/` when running `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Where do you store and how do you include the CSS? This kind of error should not occur, and is most likely not closely related to Django, but to a misplaced CSS rule or a CSS file being included that you did not mean to include. If you inspect the body using developer tools, you can see the origin of the rule (which CSS file it comes from).

Comment: About the templates: If you want to include the footer from a separate template, you should only include the necessary HTML in footer.html (i.e. you don't want to have another <html> tag inside your <body> -- think of it as copy and pasting the contents of the footer.html to index.html where the {% include %} line is.

Comment: Removing the tag {% include "templates/footer.html" %} the error goes away. It depends on the tag I believe. The CSS is stored inside the path mysite/articles/static/css/ (the full project is on github if you need to see the full path or other information https://github.com/marcogdepinto/DjangoWeb )

Comment: About the template I am afraid but I haven't understood: I created the footer.html in the templates folder of my project ( DjangoWeb/mysite/articles/templates/ ) but it is not displayed when I run python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved recoding all the website using bootstrap for responsive design and inserting the footer in the index.html.
Extract of HTML below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  {% block sidebar %}<!-- insert default navigation text for every page -->{% endblock %}
  {% block content %}<!-- default content text (typically empty) -->
  <!-- Main Logo -->
  <div class="main-image" id="myMainImage">
    <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/images/logo.png"/>
  </div>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    ...
  </nav>
  <!-- End of Navigation Bar -->

  <!-- Articles -->
  <div class="articles" id="myArticles">
    {% for article in articles %}
    <h3>Titolo: {{ article.title }}</h3>
    <p><strong>Autori:</strong> {{ article.authors }}</p>
    <p><strong>Riepilogo:</strong> {{ article.summary }}</p>
    <p><strong>Testo:</strong> {{ article.content }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <!-- End of Articles -->

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="site-footer">
    <div id="footer1">
      <p> Text </p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- End of Footer -->

  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
.site-footer {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #aa2222;
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try defining the footer section in a separate footer.html page and use the include template tag to include the html page.

Comment: Could you please add a code example? I tried to insert a footer.html file in the templates path and a tag {% include "templates/footer.html" %} in the index.html but the server goes in error TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/

Comment: keep your footer.html in the same directory as your other templates. and you can include it like {%include "footer.html" %}

Comment: Do you mean together with the other HTML (DjangoWeb/mysite/articles/templates/) or the CSS in the static folder (DjangoWeb/mysite/articles/static/)? If you want to see the full path of the project to have a clear view it is stored here:  github.com/marcogdepinto/DjangoWeb .

Comment: yes in the templates folder with the other HTML pages